# Node Js Retrieve and display image

Tags: node.js, image

I am able to upload images using Node.Js and Multer. The images are saving in encrypted format with random names. How can I retrieve and display images in a .jade file or .hetml file?

```
//My Code to upload image

router.post("/upload", function(req, res, next){
    if (req.files) { 
        console.log(util.inspect(req.files));
        if (req.files.myFile.size === 0) {
                    return next(new Error("Hey, first would you select a file?"));
        }
        fs.exists(req.files.myFile.path, function(exists) { 
            if(exists) { 
                res.end("Got your file!"); 
            } else { 
                res.end("Well, there is no magic for those who don’t believe in it!"); 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
});


// Upload page (Jade file)

    form#fileUpload(method="post" action="/uploads/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data")
        label(for="payload") Select a file to upload:
        input#fileToUpload(type='file', name='myFile')
        //input#payload(type="file" name="myFile" accept="image/*")
        br
        button#upload Upload
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var multer = require('multer'),
upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});
app.post('/multipart-upload', upload.single('file'),  function(req, res){
   var filename = req.file.path;
   console.log('Uploading File: ' + JSON.stringify(req.file));
});
```

Multer needs a path to upload the file. You can keep the path inside the public/static folder of express, and directly link the file.

Or You can use the static files middleware to serve the files in the upload folder and directly link them.

`app.use('/image-uploads', express.static('uploads'));`